# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch' by X commits. But isn't?

Tags: git, gitlab

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times, and usually I know how to solve it, but this time I'm stuck with the following scenario.

Step 1

```
git status
On branch v2.1.10-af
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/v2.1.10-af' by 13 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Step 2

```
git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Step 3

```
git status
On branch v2.1.10-af
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/v2.1.10-af'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Step 4

```
git pull
From gitlab.com:username/repo
 * [new branch]      v2.1.10-AF -> origin/v2.1.10-AF
Already up to date.
```

and again ...

```
git status
On branch v2.1.10-af
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/v2.1.10-af' by 13 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and so on in an infinite loop from Step 2.

I also tried removing and restoring my local repo

```
git branch -D v2.1.10-af
git checkout -t origin/v2.1.10-af
```

but after pulling I always get `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/v2.1.10-af' by 13 commits`.

Comment: I would try git push -u origin <nameOf OtiginBranch>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bit weird.  I think the issue here is a case-sensitivity one:

When you run `git pull` and it runs `git fetch`, you get this as one of the output lines:

> ```
>  * [new branch]      v2.1.10-AF -> origin/v2.1.10-AF
> ```

Running `git status`, however, says:

> ```
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/v2.1.10-af'.
> ```

Note that the `fetch` output uses uppercase: `origin/v2.1.10-AF`.  The `status` output uses lowercase: `origin/v2.1.10-af`.

To *Git*, these are two completely different names—and Git is storing some of this data in your repository as text lines inside ordinary text files, where they remain different names.  But Git stores some other data about branch names and remote-tracking names in *file names* as stored by your operating system.

To *your computer*, the *file* named `.git/refs/remotes/origin/v2.1.10-AF` is *the same file* as the file named `.git/refs/remotes/origin/v2.1.10-af`, even though one is uppercase and the other is lowercase.

The problem, in other words, is that Git believes that these are *different* names (and they are different on Linux machines, such as the GitHub server), but your OS sometimes insists they are the *same name*.

Your `git push` has the GitHub server create or update the lowercase name, `v2.1.10-af`.  That leaves the uppercase name, `v2.1.10-AF`, 13 commits behind.  The push is now complete and everything on GitHub is up to date.

Then, your `pull` obtains both names—`v2.1.10-af` and `v2.1.10-AF`—and stores two different commit hash IDs under these two names, but your OS insists that they're the *same* name.  The old uppercase `v2.1.10-AF` value overwrites the correct one and `git status` suddenly says you're 13 commits behind again.

To verify this is the case, use the GitHub web interface (or similar) to look at GitHub and see what names you have.  **Please do this first!**

The solution is to change the names and/or avoid mixing uppercase and lowercase.  You can, for instance, use only-lowercase by telling the GitHub server to delete the uppercase name:

```
git push --delete origin v2.1.10-AF
```

or deleting the uppercase variant through the web interface.  Now GitHub will have only the lowercase variant.  Then, in your own repository, go in and find any uppercase variants of the name in `.git/refs/remotes/origin` and remove or rename them to lowercase variants (removing these entirely is safe because `git fetch` will re-create them if appropriate).

Comment: You're absolutely right, my eyes were blindfolded. I have read and reread the same code hundreds of times without ever realizing that difference. Through the web interface I noticed that there were 2 branches "AF" and "af". It was enough to delete one. Thanks so much.